# Python 3.x Write Unicode literals as their value in file

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, literals

I'm programming on Win10 with Python 3.x. I need to connect to the Twitter API and stream Tweets. I need to store them as fully readeable ("ä" = "ä" != "\u00e4") strings in a .csv.

data is one full tweet as JSON

```
saveFile=open('twitDB.csv','a', encoding= 'utf-8')
saveFile.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False))
saveFile.write('\n')
saveFile.close()
```

I tried the code above but the umlaute are still displayed as

```
Bev\\u00f6lkerung
```

I have included `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the header but also no changes.
Does anybody has a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are they displayed as such? In Windows' console? If you open your csv with a UTF-aware editor, does it still show the escapes?

Comment: The escapes are displayed in the cmd, the .csv-File (opened with Excel365) and when I open the .csv with notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found someone who told me my error.

Apparently I switched the meaning of `json.dumps` and `json.loads`. To decode the string I have to parse the JSON with `json.loads()` and write it with a `str` conversion in the .csv-File.

Here the snippet:

```
jdata = json.loads(data) 
        saveFile=open('twitDB.csv','a', encoding='utf8') 
        cfile = csv.writer(saveFile)
        cfile.writerow([str(jdata['id']), jdata['text'], jdata['lang']])
        saveFile.close()
```